# Выталкивает нижний блок при анимации

Tags: javascript, html

При клике выпадает текст и этим смещает блок, что идет дальше по коду. А хотелось бы чтоб он выпадал поверх. С помощью добавления `position: absolute` всё работает как надо, но кнопка исчезает. Хотелось, чтоб кнопка уезжала вместе с текстом. Возможно кто-то сталкивался и поможет с этим вопросом?

https://jsfiddle.net/3cdkhkdt/7/

Comment: Извиняюсь, там был старый код с jsfiddle. Обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  var test = $(this).prev();
  if (test.innerHeight() == 0) {
    test.animate({
      height: test.prop('scrollHeight') + "px",
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    test.animate({
      height: 0,
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.showhide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.test-block {
  background-color: #E3DEDE;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="showhide">
    <p class="test-block">The best products begin with the best ingredients. Flour is milled only from select grades of the best wheat grains; the best nature has to offer, it looks like white powder. We have many varieties and formats for diverse applications.High quality
      grade. This sort of flour is pretty clear from which is preparing only from well-peeled grains. This grade of flour characterize by a low content of gluten and large amount of starch. This grade of flour has white color with a light milky shade.
      This grade often use in cooking, because batch turns out splendid and porous.The first grade of flout. This is the most popular grade, which allows for a small number of grain shells. This grade of flour is characterize large amount of gluten, which
      makes it possible to get a very elastic dough. This grade of flour has a light yellow color. Batches turns out volumetric and fragrant.The second grade of flour. This grate is characterized by a darker grayish color, which has a large number of
      grain envelopes this is allowing in the composition.</p>
    <button class="test">test</button>
  </div>
  <p>
    The first grade of flout. This is the most popular grade, which allows for a small number of grain shells. This grade of flour is characterize large amount of gluten, which makes it possible to get a very elastic dough. This grade of flour has a light
    yellow color. Batches turns out volumetric and fragrant.The second grade of flour. This grate is characterized by a darker grayish color, which has a large number of grain envelopes this is allowing in the composition.
  </p>
</div>
```

А вообще, всю вашу анимацию раскрытия/скрытия блока можно уместить **в одну строчку**:

```js
$('.test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.showhide').find('.test-block').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.showhide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.test-block {
  background-color: #E3DEDE;
  display: none;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="showhide">
    <p class="test-block">The best products begin with the best ingredients. Flour is milled only from select grades of the best wheat grains; the best nature has to offer, it looks like white powder. We have many varieties and formats for diverse applications.High quality
      grade. This sort of flour is pretty clear from which is preparing only from well-peeled grains. This grade of flour characterize by a low content of gluten and large amount of starch. This grade of flour has white color with a light milky shade.
      This grade often use in cooking, because batch turns out splendid and porous.The first grade of flout. This is the most popular grade, which allows for a small number of grain shells. This grade of flour is characterize large amount of gluten, which
      makes it possible to get a very elastic dough. This grade of flour has a light yellow color. Batches turns out volumetric and fragrant.The second grade of flour. This grate is characterized by a darker grayish color, which has a large number of
      grain envelopes this is allowing in the composition.</p>
    <button class="test">test</button>
  </div>
  <p>
    The first grade of flout. This is the most popular grade, which allows for a small number of grain shells. This grade of flour is characterize large amount of gluten, which makes it possible to get a very elastic dough. This grade of flour has a light
    yellow color. Batches turns out volumetric and fragrant.The second grade of flour. This grate is characterized by a darker grayish color, which has a large number of grain envelopes this is allowing in the composition.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за наглость, а каким способом свернуть обратно? Я за вашу js функцию в одну стркоу. И не подскажите, можно ли кнопку отобразить по центру. Так как у меня в рабочем коде идет две колонки col-lg-6 и вот под каждой из них по центру стоит картинка ввиде стрелки, кликая по ней мы открываем этот блок с описанием и наоборот. Каким способом можно отцентровать эту картинку..ну в нашем случае кнопку

Comment: @MishaRodnoy Так кнопка же и так сворачивает все обратно.

Comment: с отцентровкой я разобрался, .showhide задал width: 100%. Нет, у меня почему-то не сворачивает обратно )))

Comment: @MishaRodnoy может быть, вы неверно код скопировали? по сниппету из моего ответа видно, что кнопка как разворачивает блок, так и сворачивает его обратно.

Comment: Та вроде бы все правильно, вернул старый js код, в нем не хочет заходить в else, если высота не равна нулю

Comment: @MishaRodnoy покажите, что у вас получилось

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64533/discussion-between-misha-rodnoy-and-cheg).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обернуть текст и кнопку в блок.  Блоку задать нижний паддинг равный высоте кнопке. Блок - position:relative; У кнопки position:absolute; bottom:0; left - опционально.

Comment: Чёт не работает. Или я вас не так понял https://jsfiddle.net/3cdkhkdt/10/